# net.simonvt.menudrawer.SlidingDrawer not working in kitkat. But working in Lollipop

Tags: android, slidingdrawer

`net.simonvt.menudrawer.SlidingDrawer` is not working in Android Kitkat. But working in Android Lollipop.
**Getting error**
`java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.AbsListView$LayoutParams`

I had set `multiDexEnabled` true in `build.gradle`

also added the follwing in application

```
 @Override
 protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
      super.attachBaseContext(base);
      MultiDex.install(this);
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a custom application class defined in Android Manifest, extend it from MultiDexApplication instead of Application solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is a deprecated library. I'd suggest you take a look at [Android Navigation Drawer](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html). Also Mutidex is only used when your application exceeds Android maximum number of methods i.e. 65,536 in a single Dex file. You should only enable Multidex if your build fails because this limit has exceeded. Cheers :)

Comment: Is there any way to resolve it without changing the library?

Comment: Updated question